# How do I convert a promisified XHR to async/await?

Tags: javascript

```
function makeRequest(method, url) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
        xhr.onload = function () {
            if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
                resolve(xhr.response);
            } else {
                reject({
                    status: this.status,
                    statusText: xhr.statusText
                });
            }
        };
        xhr.onerror = function () {
            reject({
                status: this.status,
                statusText: xhr.statusText
            });
        };
        xhr.send();
    });
}
```

I know how to use the function which returns a promise using async/await but how do I convert it to async/await, no promises at all. (I know that async/await are implicitly promises).

Comment: use fetch instead?

Answer (score 4):

It is impossible. `await` (and the `async` function that it must be inside) is (for the most part) a substitute for `Promise.prototype.then` - it is *not* a substitute for `new Promise`. In other words, `await`, like `.then`, *consumes* a Promise. If you do not have any Promises available to use, you cannot use `await` (or, at least, not sensibly).

If you have something callback-based, like `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.onload`, and you want to use it with `await`, you must *both* convert it to a Promise first (as you're doing currently) and *also* `await` its Promise, eg:

```
(async () => {
  await makeRequest('GET', '/foo');
})();
```

where `makeRequest` still explicitly creates the Promise with `new Promise`.