# Rewrite Promise using async/await

Tags: typescript, async-await, promise

what is the best way to re-write the following Promise-based function using async/await?

```
  function readFileAsync(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = () => {
        const binaryStr = reader.result;
        resolve(binaryStr);
      };
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

      reader.onerror = reject;
    });
  }
```

Comment: You can't. This is "promisifying" (that's the term we use) a callback-based API.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a promisified XHR to async/await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56844887/how-do-i-convert-a-promisified-xhr-to-async-await)

Answer (score -2):

Async/await works with Promises. It lets you wait for promises in a way that reads more like regular code.

The code snippet you shared brings a non-promise asynchronous operation into the promise world. There's nothing really here to await, because you're also not using any `.then()`.